# How to debug the selenium java code in eclipse when scripting testcases with large number of test steps

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, automated-tests

How to perform dry run or debug my selenium java code in Eclipse? If am writing  script for the testcase consisting 25 steps , my script failed at 21st step. So I am adjusting my script at 21st step, for this do i need rerun from first that is all the 20 steps on each time adjusting the script ?

Please help me.

Thanks in  advance!!!

Comment: When you edit the method you are in already in the debugger, Eclipse will automatically restart that method, but it won't reset the state of the world around your method.  If your method, when executing step 21, modifies the state of the browser, and you then edit the code for step 21, Eclipse will not reset the state of the browser to what it was before your edit.  I think that, in general, the only safe thing to do is to restart from the beginning.  If you _know_ that your code as it was for step 21 did not modify the state of the browser, maybe you could let Eclipse retry that step...

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if your steps are connected you will have to run from the beginning every time. That is why it is recommended to keep test cases for automation small and independent, simply because it is hard and costly to maintain and make the really stable. As a suggestion try to split it into multiple independent test cases.
For example, if your test case looks like

1. action 1: 
   check 1
2. action 2:
   check 2
3. action 3: 
   check 3

You can have 3 automation tests looking like (pseudo code):

Test 1.

```
beforeTest1() {
  makeSystemForTest1();
}

test1() {
  action1();
  check1();
}
```

Test 2.

```
beforeTest2() {
  makeSystemForTest2();
}

test2() {
  action2();
  check2();
}
```

Test 3.

```
beforeTest3() {
  makeSystemForTest3();
}

test3() {
  action3();
  check3();
}
```